# Getting server response from DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

My application downloads files using Android `DownloadManager`. If download is failed for some reason (for example file doesn't exists anymore) my server provides me with XML response containing problem description. But it seems that in `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` receiver I can only get HTTP status code.

**My question is:** Can I actually somehow get XML server response (or just raw response) in `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` receiver? 
For now I can see only variant with sending extra request if download is failed.